# Difference between two overloads of Enumerable.Except?

Tags: c#, linq, except, iequalitycomparer

I am trying to understand the difference between two overloads of `Enumerable.Except` method i.e.

- Except(IEnumerable, IEnumerable)
- Except(IEnumerable, IEnumerable,
  IEqualityComparer)

Obviously, the first differnce is that the first overload uses the default equality comparer while the other uses an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151(v=vs.100).aspx), but I can achieve the same result with first method, by implementing an [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface (as mentioned in the MSDN documentation of `Except` method), then why this second overload is needed?

Comment: Well, just for the cases when you can't implement `IEquatable` interface by some reason (for example - if it's not your class), but still want to use custom comparer.

Comment: Maybe you want to use it on 2 `IEnuemrable<SomeThirdPartyClass>` but you cannot modify `SomeThirdPartyClass`, then you must use the second overload.

Comment: Sometimes there are several applicable equality rules for an object, depending on the context. IEquatable really provides one use case, so in those situations, you need to define the alternative comparer, and the second overload of `Except`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. You can only implement `IEquatable<T>` for your own types... whereas you can specify an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for *any* type, whether you can modify it yourself or not.
2. There may be multiple ways of comparing a type for equality, but implementing `IEquatable<T>` only allows you to express one of them.

A simple example of all of this would be strings - consider:

```
string[] x = { "A", "B", "C" };
string[] y = { "A", "c" };

var bc = x.Except(y);
var justB = x.Except(y, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

We might want both results in different circumstances, which means we couldn't handle both with `IEquatable<T>`... and we can't change how `string` implements `IEquatable<T>` anyway. (You're not limited to `StringComparer` of course - you could write an equality comparer which just used the length of the string, for example.)

This isn't specific to LINQ, either - it's generally the case for any API which deals in equality, e.g. `HashSet<>`, `Dictionary<,>` etc.

Comment: Thank You Jon! Very well explained :)